# How to create listview in android using two different size dynamic ArrayList?

Tags: android

I follow the give link:
[Android ListView adapter with two ArrayLists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29788684/android-listview-adapter-with-two-arraylists)

But on above link solution add both arraylist to a single ArrayList. can please suggest any answer as my requirement given below:

Requirement: I am getting data from server that is both different API so how to set to listview after parsing?

Please suggest any solution
Thanks in advance

Comment: I assume that you need to put heterogeneous items in the list. Right? You can create an additional class and put only those fields from both which is required for use. Alternatively, there are many other ways to achieve the same.

Comment: Yes, can you please share any link please

Answer (score 1):

there are a few things you can do in this case:

1. model your data in an inheritance (or interface) model to allow abstracting your data to a unified type and display it while using `getItemViewType` do differentiate the data
2. use a 3rd party library such as [mergelist](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-merge) and use 2 different adapters

Answer (score 1):

When your Model isn't same for both of the two, then you can create a interface named CustomInterface and implement it to both of your models. Then in the adapter, instead of the model, use CustomInterface and in your getView, you have to check the current model like:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
LayoutInflater theInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
View theView = theInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row, parent, false);
if(entity instanceof Obj1){
    // Model 1
} else if(entity instanceof Obj2){
    // Model 2
}
return theView;
}
```

Remember that, List works only for homogeneous collections. If you have heterogeneous collection, you can implement interface on all of the models and make a List of the interface and then can put any model within that list which implement same interface.

Comment: Thanks yasir sir, now i got it.

Comment: If this solve your problem, kindly mark it as correct answer

Answer (score 1):

sample here.

1. interface

   ```
   public interface DataType {
           String getTitle();
           String getAddress();
   }
   ```
2. data class

   ```
   public class AData implements DataType {
       String titleA;
       String addressA;

       @Override
       public String getTitle() {
           return titleA;
       }

       @Override
       public String getAddress() {
           return addressA;
       }

       // getter & setter
   }

   public class BData implements DataType {
       String titleB;
       String addressB;

       @Override
       public String getTitle() {
           return titleB;
       }

       @Override
       public String getAddress() {
           return addressB;
       }

       // getter & setter
   }
   ```
3. adapter

   ```
   public class CustomAdapter implements BaseAdapter {

   List<DataType> arrayList;

   // getCount...

   @Override
   public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
       // inflating views, bindings, reuse, etc

       DataType data = arrayList.get(position);
       textView.setText(data.getTitle());
       textView.setText(data.getAddress());

       // return ...

   }
   ```